# Linux Mint 18 freezes after a while with connected Android Nexus 5X

Tags: adb, usb, linux

I am developing Android apps using Android Studio 2.2.3 with my Linux Mint Cinnamon 18 laptop.  After a while of having my Nexus phone connected to my computer the laptop will hang and I can't click on anything or initiate any action (on laptop).  Simply unplugging my Nexus fixes the issue but I would like to know the cause and solution so I can just keep the Nexus phone connected when I am using it as a development test device.

Under Developer Options on the Nexus running 7.1.1 I have "Stay awake" checked.  USB debugging is checked. USB configuration MTB.

Error messages during the time this happens:

```
Jun 11 10:09:34 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3387]: ** (process:3692): WARNING **: send_done_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/3 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
Jun 11 11:18:11 -Satellite-L55-B cinnamon-screensaver-pam-helper: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error
Jun 11 13:45:21 -Satellite-L55-B dockerd[2204]: time="2017-06-11T13:45:20.879600451-07:00" level=error msg="libcontainerd: failed to receive event from containerd: rpc error: code = 13 desc = transport is closing"
Jun 11 14:20:23 -Satellite-L55-B kernel: [   17.770092] EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Jun 11 14:20:34 -Satellite-L55-B nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [virbr0-nic], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown' exited with error status 1.
Jun 11 14:20:35 -Satellite-L55-B NetworkManager[1189]:   [1497216035.7009] dispatcher: (3) 01ifupdown failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown' exited with error status 1.
Jun 11 15:01:34 -Satellite-L55-B systemd-sleep[7962]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Jun 11 15:01:34 -Satellite-L55-B systemd-sleep[7987]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Jun 11 15:19:22 -Satellite-L55-B systemd-sleep[7962]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Jun 11 15:19:22 -Satellite-L55-B systemd-sleep[8086]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Jun 11 15:19:48 -Satellite-L55-B cinnamon-screensaver-pam-helper: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error
Jun 11 15:59:25 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: Error 2: PTP Layer error 02ff: Error getting friendlyname.
Jun 11 15:59:25 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: Error 2: Error 02ff: PTP: I/O error
Jun 11 15:59:28 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: PTP: reading event an error 0x02ff occurredError 2: PTP Layer error 02ff: Error getting friendlyname.
Jun 11 15:59:28 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: Error 2: Error 02ff: PTP: I/O error
Jun 11 16:02:29 -Satellite-L55-B libvirtd[1405]: nl_recv returned with error: No buffer space available
Jun 11 16:18:55 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: PTP: reading event an error 0x02ff occurredError 2: PTP Layer error 02ff: Error getting friendlyname.
Jun 11 16:18:55 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: Error 2: Error 02ff: PTP: I/O error
Jun 11 16:18:55 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: Error 2: PTP Layer error 02ff: Error getting friendlyname.
Jun 11 16:18:55 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: Error 2: Error 02ff: PTP: I/O error
Jun 11 16:22:23 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: PTP: reading event an error 0x02ff occurredDevice 0 (VID=18d1 and PID=4ee1) is a Google Inc (for LG Electronics/Samsung) Nexus 4/5/7/10 (MTP).
Jun 11 16:22:34 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: PTP: reading event an error 0x02ff occurredDevice 0 (VID=18d1 and PID=4ee1) is a Google Inc (for LG Electronics/Samsung) Nexus 4/5/7/10 (MTP).
Jun 11 16:23:30 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: PTP: reading event an error 0x02ff occurredDevice 0 (VID=18d1 and PID=4ee2) is a Google Inc (for LG Electronics/Samsung) Nexus 4/5/7/10 (MTP+ADB).
Jun 11 16:38:11 -Satellite-L55-B cinnamon-screensaver-pam-helper: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error
Jun 11 16:50:58 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: PTP: reading event an error 0x02ff occurredDevice 0 (VID=18d1 and PID=4ee2) is a Google Inc (for LG Electronics/Samsung) Nexus 4/5/7/10 (MTP+ADB).
Jun 11 17:47:07 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: PTP: reading event an error 0x02ff occurredError 2: PTP Layer error 02ff: Error getting friendlyname.
Jun 11 17:47:07 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: Error 2: Error 02ff: PTP: I/O error
Jun 11 17:47:07 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: Error 2: PTP Layer error 02ff: Error getting friendlyname.
Jun 11 17:47:07 -Satellite-L55-B org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[3308]: Error 2: Error 02ff: PTP: I/O error
```

Comment: That might rather be an issue on the Linux end. Have you checked the logs? For example, `/var/log/syslog` on the Linux machine? Checking the Android logs might bring up something as well (see our [logging tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info). I cannot speak for Android Studio (which might have its part in it as well), but I never experienced that here (also running Mint, and have some of my devices attached for longer time). If there are logs created by Studio, check them as well. Then [edit] your question and update it with your findings. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Process '/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxCreateUSBNode.sh 189 133 00' failed with exit code 1.  org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[2197]: Device 0 (VID=18d1 and PID=4ee2) is a Google Inc (for LG Electronics/Samsung) Nexus 4/5/7/10 (MTP+ADB).
Mar 19 14:31:14 org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[2197]: Error 1: Get Storage information failed.  // these errors occurred around the time of freeze

Comment: here are more errors during the time the computer froze with my android connected:

Comment: As I wrote, that rather seems an issue on the Linux end (here: `libmtp`), so you might have better luck at our corresponding sister site (most likely Unux&Linux, as AskUbuntu doesn't like Mint AFAIR). OTOH: I'm using Mint 18.1 as well, with multiple devices, and never had that issue. You could try setting your N5 to PTP (if it's on MTP currently, otherwise to MTP) or "charge only" (and in the latter case hope that ADB isn't switched off as well in case you need that – but if your Mint freezes, it doesn't help to have MTP or ADB if you cannot use it anyway).